# Explicit solutions to a digamma function equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, digamma-function

> **My main question:**
>   Can we obtain the exact solutions from the following equation?
>
> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cfrac{1}{k-x-1}=0 $$

**Notation:** This problem was reached from the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) $\psi$ as follows:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cfrac{1}{k-x-1}=\psi(n-x)-\psi(-x)
$$

Generally, any polynomial equations can be solved exactly until four order as the quartic equation. Nevertheless, in high order case in this problem $(n\geq 6)$, we can also obtain the exact solutions. Here is a table which is described since beginning of $n=2$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{equation} && && \text{solutions} \\
\psi(2-x)=\psi(-x) && \cfrac{1}{2} \\
\psi(3-x)=\psi(-x) && 1\pm\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\psi(4-x)=\psi(-x) && \cfrac{3}{2} && \cfrac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} \\
\psi(5-x)=\psi(-x) && 2\pm\sqrt{\cfrac{15\pm\sqrt{145}}{10}} \\
\psi(6-x)=\psi(-x) && \cfrac{5}{2} && \cfrac{5}{2}\pm\cfrac{\sqrt{3(35\pm 8\sqrt{7})}}{6} \\
\vdots && \vdots && \vdots
\end{aligned}
$$

Furthermore, suppose $n=8$ and $n=9$ cases (Of course, other cases are true) and these algebraic solutions are existed:

[solutions of $n=8$ by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bsum%5B1%2F(k-x-1),%7Bk,1,2%5E3%7D%5D%3D%3D0,x%5D)

[solutions of $n=9$ by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bsum%5B1%2F(k-x-1),%7Bk,1,2%5E3%2B1%7D%5D%3D%3D0%5D)

Additionally, these approximate solutions are estimated on each equation and the diagram is shown below:

[image]

Then, horizontal axis is $x$ and the vertical axis is $n$. Expressions of periodic functions can be expected because we can see a periodical pattern from diagrams. In fact, these solutions including nested rationals have deep relations with trigonometric functions. Example of expressions are shown below  (if you want to know further, we can see [this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals) and [this paper](https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf).):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin\cfrac{\pi}{10}=&\cfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} && 
\cos\cfrac{\pi}{10}=&\cfrac{\sqrt{2(5+\sqrt{5})}}{4} &&
\tan\cfrac{\pi}{10}=&\cfrac{\sqrt{ 5(5-2\sqrt{5}) }}{5} \\
\sin\cfrac{\pi}{5}=&\cfrac{\sqrt{2(5-\sqrt{5})}}{4} && 
\cos\cfrac{\pi}{5}=&\cfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4} &&
\tan\cfrac{\pi}{5}=&\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}
\end{aligned}
$$

And reflection formula may be useful knowledge:

$$
\psi(1-x)-\psi(x)=\pi\cot(\pi x)
$$

As the above description, we can guess that these solutions can be converted into trigonometric functions. I am very glad that someone indicates any advises or references.

Comment: When $n$ is even you can set $x-1$ equal to the average of $1,2,\cdots,n$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I think that Mr. Claude Leibovici (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici) has something to say on that.

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by *periodical relation* ? In any manner, I do not think that exact solutions could be obtained if $n\geq 5$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I have added more mention.

Comment: One can do better than $n\leqslant4$... If $n=5$, the solutions are the roots of a polynomial of degree $4$, hence the case is analytically solvable. If $n=6$, the solutions are the roots of a polynomial of degree $5$ but $\frac52$ is an obvious root, hence the case is analytically solvable. If $n\geqslant7$, I see no reason to expect that the case is analytically solvable.

Comment: @Hayabusananji. If you are concerned by this problem (forgetting analytical solutions), we could discuss. Try to have a look to a paper published in **Computers and Chemical Engineering, vol. 74 (2014) pp.574-590**. If you wish, contact me by e-mail (my address is in my profile).

Comment: It's not hard to show that there is a zero in each interval $[k-1,k]$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$. Approximations for the solutions rather than exact results should be much easier to obtain.